# RabbitMQ C# connection trouble when using a username and password

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am at a loss here so I'm reaching out to the collective knowledge in hope of a miracle.

I have installed RabbitMQ on a Linux box using the defaults.

When I use this code (and the default RabbitMQ installation configuration) everything works nice.

```
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.HostName = "192.168.0.12";
IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

But when I add a user to RabbitMQ and try to use the following code (username and password has been changed to protect the innocent. :) )

```
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.HostName = "192.168.0.12";
connectionFactory.UserName = "user";
connectionFactory.Password = "password";
IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

the `connectionFactory.CreateConnection()` method throws the following exception:

```
BrokerUnreachableException    
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

Checking the RabbitMQ logfile I can see it complaining about the credentials:

```
{amqp_error,access_refused,
"PLAIN login refused: user 'user' - invalid credentials",
'connection.start_ok'}}
```

The thing is that I am confident about the username and password and I cannot for the love of coding find a solution to this anywhere.

I must be missing something obvious but I can't figure out what it is.
I would be grateful for any helpful pointers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that I have found a solution to my own problem.
The following code works:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "user";
factory.Password = "password";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Protocol = Protocols.FromEnvironment();
factory.HostName = "192.168.0.12";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Thanks for listening and perhaps this at least could be useful to someone else. :)

Comment: Hi ! I am also trying to establish connection to send messages. I have searched but not satisfied. Can you please suggest me something. That, do we also need to install rabbitMQ server before using the above code. I am using above code after adding reference of DLL so there is no error in the project but it stll gives the above said exception. Do we also need to add some things in WEB.Config File. Please help. Your point of view will really help me

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not answering earlier. I played with RabbitMQ for only a short while so I have not much experience with it. I do remember having a RabbitMQ instance running so you'd probably need that as well. Regarding the web.config file I'm afraid I don't know if I ever used it.

Comment: FWIW, the salient lines for me were setting the `VirtualHost` and `Protocol`.

Comment: Additionally: make sure the user actually has access rights to the Virtual Host

Comment: Does it work for username/password as guest? Mine not working :( and it doesn't recognize FromEnvironment()

Comment: Hi Imad. Sorry but I am unable to answer your question as I don't have a setup to test in anymore. Hopefully some other kind Stackoverflow:er can help you.

Comment: As of year 2020, this is no need to specify Protocol. One thing to highlight is make sure the user has been configured correctly on the RabbitMQ-Server, it has to be admin, has permissions to read and write like @mihail said and also has access to "/" virtualHost

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to create a user called `agent` with password `agent`, set it to be `administrator` and give it `read` and `write` access to all queues in the vhost /

```
rabbitmqctl add_user agent agent
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags agent administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / agent ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (on Windows).

I had to install the management tools:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

*N.B. rabbitmq-plugins is in C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.1\sbin*

Then, restart the RabbitMQ service.

I then installed EasyNetQ in Visual Studio in the package manager:

```
install-package easynetq
```

With this installed, I could use the admin web site located at:

```
http://localhost:15672
```

N.B. The default username and password is: guest

From here, I selected the Admin tab and the cause was clearly displayed in yellow at the top of the screen:

```
This user does not have permission to access any virtual hosts.
Use "Set Permission" below to grant permission to access virtual hosts.
```

To fix the issue I just pressed the **Set permission** button on the same screen et voila

N.B. for this to have worked you need to have added the user using **rabbitmqctl add_user username password** or similar (rabbitmqctl is also in the directory above).