# RabbitMQ Connection Error " None of the specified endpoints were reachable"

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq service on  the server and on my system.
I want to use RPC pattern:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { 
  HostName = "158.2.14.42", 
  Port = Protocols.DefaultProtocol.DefaultPort, 
  UserName = "Administrator", 
  Password = "@server@", 
  VirtualHost = "/"
  ContinuationTimeout = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0, 0) 
};

connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

I have an error on creating connection with this message:

None of the specified endpoints were reachable

When I use it on localhost instance of the server it works, but when I create the connection from local to that server,it returned the error.
It not work with local ip and username and password of the my local computer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ C# connection trouble when using a username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987438/rabbitmq-c-sharp-connection-trouble-when-using-a-username-and-password)

Comment: @RazvanDumitru , I do like that but still have the error.
and code doesn't recognize **FromEnvironment**

Comment: @RazvanDumitru Thank you,your guidance helped me.

Comment: @parsa what you have done for FromEnvironment  ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4987438) mentioned.
After I installed RabbitMQ, I enabled management tools on the server and on my local computer with this:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Then I restarted RabbitMQ service from `services.msc`

I could see the Rabbitmq management at `http://localhost:15672`

I logged in to rabbit management with user:guest and pass:guest

I added my favorite user pass with administrator access, so it worked.

Comment: In my case I was working with another VHost, so go to "Users" => and then click on the "virtual host" dropdown, select your VHost and click on "set permission". Works like a charm

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing the same issue and later realized I have to open both ports i.e. 15672 and 5672.

The below command works for me in the docker container model.

```
docker run -it --rm --name mymq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Code snippet:

```
 var factory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory
            {
                Uri = new Uri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
            };
```

or

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use guest. Create your own account and password, and in http://localhost:15672/#/users , ensure "can access virtual hosts  "  is  "/"

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { 
  HostName = "192.168.1.121",
  Port = 5672,
  UserName = "fancky", 
  Password = "123456" 
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In our case it was an assembly binding failure of `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, our exception logger was not logging the `InnerException`

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileLoadException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection..ctor(ConnectionFactory factory, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName) in /_/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs:line 494
```

Very poor misleading error message.

Answer (score 2):

**If the project is dockerized:**

`host.docker.internal` (or appropriate URL...) should be used instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

it means that the client can't reach the server `158.2.14.42` and default vhost `/`.

Maybe a firewall configuration

Comment: I Add **5672** port on widnows firewall of server, but it not solved.

Comment: Any recommendation? is there any solution that I must be do that?

Answer (score 1):

By default as you say RabbitMQ will listen on `5672` but this can be changed, if you have a look at your config (on the MQ server) you should find a section:

`rabbit.tcp_listeners`

which will detail the port being used. Check it's what you think it is.

Also, are you using IPv4 or IPv6? you may need to have additional config to support both.

Have a read of this:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

Comment: It says as the default, RabbitMQ will listen on port 5672 on all available interfaces.
on config file,must be I change on anything?

Answer (score 1):

1) Open RabbitMQ Command Promp

2) Change path to "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.10\sbin" where rabbitmq_server installed.

3) Run following commamd : 
**rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management**

If Firewall has blocked it, then popup display. Allow Firewall for this.

now you can access in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Misleading error. The local version works ok but the remote server didn't. Turned out I did not supply the credentials i.e. username and password which are mandatory for remote server. Local server happily connects without them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing this very issue, and in the end it was just about having provided the URI as lowercase, while the name of the machine was uppercase.

As it took a couple of hours to figure it out, I thought it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small application using .netcore and rabbitmq and created the image in docker for both of them using below docker-compose code -

```
version: '3'
services:
rabbitmq:
container_name: rabbitmq
hostname: "rabbitmq"
image: rabbitmq:3-management
ports:
- "5672:5672"
- "15672:15672"
volumes:
- rabbitmq:/rabbitmq
healthcheck:
test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
interval: 30s
timeout: 10s
retries: 5

isp_hub:
depends_on:
- rabbitmq
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
- "9090:80"

volumes:
rabbitmq:

after running the cmd docker-compose up the image is created and container is started and i am using Jmeter client to hit the container .net code is working but while trying to pass the data in queue getting below exception -

"log":"info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:22.6109672Z"}
{"log":" Application is shutting down...\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:22.6109672Z"}
{"log":"info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4488984Z"}
{"log":" Now listening on: http://[::]:80\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4488984Z"}
{"log":"info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":" Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":"info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":" Hosting environment: Production\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":"info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":" Content root path: C:\app\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:25:38.4498991Z"}
{"log":"fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" Failed to invoke hub method 'SendToMessageBroker'.\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" ---\u003e System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" ---\u003e RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" ---\u003e System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.\u003c\u003ec.\u003c.cctor\u003eb__4_0(Object state)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" --- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingAddressFamily(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout, AddressFamily family)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"} {"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingIPv4(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"} {"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func2 selector)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"} {"log":" --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"} {"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func2 selector)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at ISP_Hub.HubConfig.CenterHub.SendToMessageBroker(String requestData) in C:\src\ISP_Hub\HubConfig\CenterHub.cs:line 38\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.\u003c\u003ec__DisplayClass33_0.\u003cWrapVoidMethod\u003eb__0(Object target, Object[] parameters)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}
{"log":" at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher1.ExecuteMethod(ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, Hub hub, Object[] arguments)\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"} {"log":" at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher1.\u003c\u003ec__DisplayClass16_0.\u003c\u003cInvoke\u003eg__ExecuteInvocation|0\u003ed.MoveNext()\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-04-04T08:26:55.7889752Z"}

rabbitmq connection code -

public void SendToMessageBroker(string requestData)
{
var trace = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestData);
// string rabbitMqUrl = "127.0.0.1";
// var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "172.24.17.225", Port = 5672 };
//var factory = new ConnectionFactory
//{
// HostName = rabbitMqUrl,
// UserName = "guest",
// Password = "guest",
// Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
// VirtualHost = "/",
// RequestedHeartbeat = new TimeSpan(60),
// Ssl = { ServerName = rabbitMqUrl, Enabled = false }
//};
var factory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory
{
Uri = new Uri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
};
using var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = conn.CreateModel();
RabbitMQPublisher.Publish(channel, trace);
Clients.All.SendAsync("test");
channel.Close();
conn.Close();
Debug.WriteLine("Show Message: " + requestData);

    }
i am new to docker . please help me to understand the issue and how to resolve it
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31451646)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps you but it happen after update RabbitMQ.Client from 5.1.2 to 5.2.0 for .net 4.6.1.
If you rise target framework to 4.8  it goes through.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I created a user of `guest` with password `guest` and apparently that does not work. Once I chose a different username and password, it worked for me.