# MassTransit RabbitMq remote connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am having trouble connecting to rabbitMq on remote server to public ip using masstransit. Let's say ip is 000.000.0.00.

While starting an app the next error is shown

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

```
x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
{
    var rabbitMqUri = new Uri("rabbitmq://000.000.0.00");
    config.Host(rabbitMqUri, h =>
    {
        h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQ:UserName"]);
        h.Password(configuration["RabbitMq:Password"]);
    });
})
```

Comment: Did these two links answer your question? [RabbitMQ C# connection trouble when using a username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987438/rabbitmq-c-sharp-connection-trouble-when-using-a-username-and-password), [RabbitMQ Connection Error " None of the specified endpoints were reachable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869390/rabbitmq-connection-error-none-of-the-specified-endpoints-were-reachable)

Comment: Did you allow inbound port from firewall?